# Installing LiClipse 2.4.0, not launching

Tags: python

I recently installed LiClipse on my virtual Ubuntu Machine following these steps:

```
Download latest version of LiClipse from the official website.

Extract the downloaded file using the command tar xvzf <filename>.
For example: tar xvzf liclipse_1.0.0_linux.gtk.x86.tar.gz

Move the extracted folder to /opt folder using the command
sudo mv liclipse /opt

Now create a shortcut of LiClipse in the applications folder using the below given command
sudo ln -s /opt/liclipse/LiClipse /usr/bin/liclipse

For shortcut:
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/liclipse.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0.0
Name=LiClipse
Comment=IDE for Python/Django developers
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/liclipse/LiClipse
Icon=/opt/liclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;Development;IDE
```

I replaced all the necessary things in this and I have my LiClipse icon right there but when I click on Launch, nothing happens. Any idea why? 
[image: Dash search]
[image: Desktop entry]

Comment: have you tried using terminal?...

Comment: Ok it worked using terminal. How can I make the shortcut work too?

Comment: in terminal what is the command you used?,,,,did you used `sudo`?

Comment: I wrote in my initial post all the commands I used. I used sudo for every command.

Comment: sorry...I mean to launch from terminal,...did you used `sudo`....please try my answer...

Comment: to launch I went into my liclipse folder and used ./liclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed a **star** (*) before file name....it mean you are not saved the file.Please click on **save**.

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/liclipse.desktop
```

Change version number

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.4.0
Name=LiClipse
Comment=IDE for Python/Django developers
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/liclipse/LiClipse
Icon=/opt/liclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;Development;IDE
```

---

Just know I tested....

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I want to launch it from desktop shortcut

Comment: @Charlotte45 please wait a minute,...I just installed..

Comment: I did change the version number the first time. No idea why it won't launch

Comment: please see my answer...that is Desktop,not`desktop`....now run the command in my answer....

Comment: I added one more photo, can you tell me if it's ok? http://i.stack.imgur.com/6UWfb.png why is utility and all in red?

Comment: @Charlotte45 I see a star before file name? ....any way no problem....try my answer......please

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to and it still doesn't work :| I don't know why

Comment: @Charlotte45 see my updated answer.....you are not saved the file

Comment: I did save it after and I got errors in my terminal when I saved http://imgur.com/1s6jUIC

Comment: @Charlotte45 for got about errors,,...I too get...are you able to launch?

Comment: No. It won't let me launch :/ only from terminal

Comment: @Charlotte45 ok....give me last chance....now I changed my answer from `Desktop ` to `desktop`.....please follow as it is...

Comment: It works now :D thank you. I did it differently. I went into /usr/share/applications/ found liclipse, clicked copy, paste on desktop and changed permissions for execute

Comment: glad to hear...@Charlotte45